# Find string beetwen first occurence of word and before first occurence of special character

Tags: regex, powershell

I have following log string and I need to get from them only `MedSoftware` part, which means

- after `.com\`
- before first occurence of `\`

> SERVERNAME2018-03-08 18:40:28 File: "x:_default\app.address.com\MedSoftware.data\BackEnd.Technical.Dictionaries.Service-180308182311\Web.config", Name: "dictionaries_data_product", CS: "###connectionStrings.dictionariesdataproduct.connectionString" info: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. 6069

Now my regex looks like this:

```
((?<=.com\\).*(?=\\))
```

and catches all after `.com` but goes to LAST occurence of `\`

Comment: Add language tag please

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`((?<=.com\\)[^\\]*(?=\\))`](https://regex101.com/r/uOKrKX/1)

I basically replaced `.*` by `[^\\]*` so that it stops at the first occurence of `\`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uOKrKX/1)

Comment: after adding `[^\\]*` you don't need to keep `(?=\\)`

Comment: Depends if OP wants to only match `.....com\xxx\ ` and not `.....com\xxx`

Comment: You are correct :)

Answer (score -1):

```
\.com\\([^\\]+)\\.*
```

Imho you don't need something to capture the first com specifically, because that's what RE's normally do anyhow. And if you capture anything but backslashes, that doesn't need greedy-specifiers either. Only the backslashes which need masking, as well as the literal dot, are a bit tricky.

The capturing group \1 or $1 or whatever it is on powershell, contains MedSoftware now.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8UEIS/3)